# notify controller action method from other independent handler within specific time

Tags: asynchronous, events, notifications, elixir

I have a situation where I need to wait for response from device(using mqtt broker which doesnt matter in current questions context).

Whenever I get an API call on one specific endpoint

- I need to wait(2-5 seconds depending upon the need) for response from device on the other handler(mqtt handler => https://github.com/gausby/tortoise)
- this handler needs to notify me somehow I got this msg(if handler received msg withing that time) for the particular device id
- if device matches and controller action method get notified we send back success response otherwise we send failure response
- Any msg received before or after wait time doesnt matter(just consider it unsubscribed)

I am not really sure about whats the best way to achieve above requirement. any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`spawn()` a process for the first handler.  In the first handler, `spawn()` another process for the second handler passing `self()` as one of the arguments. Then enter a `receive` clause with a 2-5 second timeout specified in the `after clause`.  Have the second handler `send()` a message to the first handler with the data that the second handler acquires.

If the `receive` in the first handler times out, then do whatever you want to do in the `after` clause, if the `receive` reads a message before it times out, then do whatever you need to do with the data.

Then, if you let the process running the first handler die, then you won't have to worry about junk messages in its mailbox.